Duplicate Kotlin class error after configuring Firebase in newly-created Flutter project
I ran the following command
flutter create --platforms=android,ios my-flutter-app

I then opened Android Studio and ran the app successfully.
Then I created a Firebase project and ran the following commands as specified by the Firebase console:
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure --project=my-firebase-project
flutter pub add firebase_core

When I tried to run again in Android Studio, I got the following:
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
I did no hand-editing of any project file so this was most likely caused by the Firebase-related commands, but how do I find the cause?

After looking at some similar questions on SO, the solution for my issue was different than any of the answers to those questions. What worked for me was to edit settings.gradle and update the Kotlin plugin version from 1.7.10 to 1.8.22.
Before:
plugins {
    ...
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

After:
plugins {
    ...
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

